# can you help me how to breakdown the denomination of my change? I've been searching everywhere how to do it but I still don't get it

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class OrderingSystemAlternative {
static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

static String [] Bread = {"Cheese Bread","Bagel","Ham and Cheese Bread","Vegetable Sandwich","Choco 
Bread Pudding",
                          "French Toast","Garlic Toast","Tuna Bread","Pizza Bread","Croissant"};
static String [] Cake = {"Blueberry", "Cheesecake", "Dark Chocolate", "Chocolate Fudge", "Creme 
Brulee", "Mocha",
                         "Ube", "Red Velvet", "Chiffon", "Mango Mania"};
static String [] Coffee = {"Americano", "Latte", "Machiatto", "Espresso", "Black Coffee", "Mocha", 
"Cappuccino",
                           "Double Espresso", "Hot Chocolate", "Caramel Machiatto"};
static String [] Donut = {"Plain", "Glazed", "Chocolate Frosted", "Rainbow Sprinkles", "Alcapone", 
"Oreology",
                          "Butternut", "Jelly Filling", "Bavarian", "Cookies & Cream"};
static String [] Tea = {"Cheesecake Oreo", "Chestnut Cream", "Cream Cheese Cocoa", "Cranberry", 
"Black Pearl", "Mango Yakult",
                        "Caramel Machiatto", "Matcha", "Taro", "Oolong Tea"}; 
static double [] breadPrice = {20.00, 13.00, 25.00, 32.00, 45.00, 27.00, 20.00, 25.00, 55.00, 10.00};
static double [] cakePrice = {500.00, 350.00, 200.00, 230.00, 550.00, 200.00, 150.00, 430.00, 150.00, 
550.00};
static double [] coffeePrice = {65.00, 80.00, 90.00, 63.00, 75.00, 70.00, 85.00, 70.00, 65.00, 
100.00};
static double [] donutPrice = {35.00, 40.00, 40.00, 40.00, 80.00, 70.00, 85.00, 80.00, 50.00, 
100.00};
static double [] teaPrice = {160.00, 155.00, 155.00, 140.00, 130.00, 140.00, 195.00, 165.00, 130.00, 
155.00};

static double subTotal = 0;
static double grandTotal = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    showMenu();
    order();
}

private static void showMenu() {
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t+===================================+");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t                Cafe MENU            ");
    System.out.println("\n"); 
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t             A. Bread & Toast        ");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  1. Cheese Bread          Php. 20.00");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  2. Bagel                 Php. 13.00");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  3. Ham and Cheese Bread  Php. 25.00");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  4. Vegetable Sandwich    Php. 32.00");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  5. Choco Bread Pudding   Php. 45.00");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  6. French Toast          Php. 27.00");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  7. Garlic Toast          Php. 20.00");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  8. Tuna Bread            Php. 25.00");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  9. Pizza Bread           Php. 55.00");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  10. Croissant            Php. 10.00");
    System.out.println(""); 
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t                B. Cakes             ");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  1. Blueberry            Php. 500.00");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  2. Cheesecake           Php. 350.00");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  3. Dark Chocolate       Php. 200.00");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  4. Chocolate Fudge      Php. 230.00");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  5. Creme Brulee         Php. 550.00");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  6. Mocha                Php. 200.00");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  7. Ube                  Php. 150.00");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  8. Red Velvet           Php. 430.00");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  9. Chiffon              Php. 150.00");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  10. Mango Mania         Php. 550.00");
    System.out.println(""); 
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t               C. Donuts             ");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  1. Plain                 Php. 35.00");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  2. Glazed                Php. 40.00");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  3. Chocolate Frosted     Php. 40.00");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  4. Rainbow Sprinkles     Php. 40.00");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  5. Alcapone              Php. 80.00");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  6. Oreology              Php. 70.00");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  7. Butternut             Php. 85.00");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  8. Jelly Filling         Php. 80.00");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  9. Bavarian              Php. 50.00");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  10. Cookies & Cream     Php. 100.00");
    System.out.println(""); 
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t                D. Coffee            ");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  1. Americano             Php. 65.00");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  2. Latte                 Php. 80.00");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  3. Machiatto             Php. 90.00");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  4. Espresso              Php. 63.00");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  5. Black Coffee          Php. 75.00");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  6. Mocha                 Php. 70.00");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  7. Cappuccino            Php. 85.00");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  8. Double Espresso       Php. 70.00");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  9. Hot Chocolate         Php. 65.00");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  10. Caramel Machiatto   Php. 100.00");
    System.out.println("");        
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t                  E. Tea             ");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  1. Cheesecake Oreo      Php. 160.00");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  2. Chestnut Cream       Php. 155.00");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  3. Cream Cheese Cocoa   Php. 155.00");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  4. Cranberry            Php. 140.00");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  5. Black Pearl          Php. 130.00");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  6. Mango Yakult         Php. 140.00");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  7. Caramel Machiatto    Php. 195.00");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  8. Matcha               Php. 165.00");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  9. Taro                 Php. 130.00");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  10. Oolong Tea          Php. 155.00");
    System.out.println(""); 
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t                0. Cancel            ");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t+===================================+");
    System.out.println("\n");
}

private static void order() {
    System.out.println("Enter \"A\" for Bread & Toast , \"B\" for Cakes , \"C\" for Donuts, \"D\" for 
 Coffee, \"E\" for Tea and \"0\" to Cancel");
    System.out.print("Choose your Taste: ");
    String picked = scanner.next();
    
    switch (picked.toLowerCase()) { 
        case "a":
            breadAndToast();
            break;
        case "b":
            cakes();
            break;
        case "c":
            donuts();
            break;
        case "d":
            coffee();
            break;
        case "e":
            tea();
            break;
        case "0":
            System.exit(0);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Choose From A to E only or Enter 0 to Cancel!");
            order();
    }
}

private static void breadAndToast() {
    System.out.println("You chose Bread & Toast");
    System.out.print("What's Your Choice? ");
    
    int choice = 0;
    try {
        String choiceStr = scanner.next();
        choice = Integer.parseInt(choiceStr);
        
        if (choice < 1 || choice - 1 > Bread.length) {
            System.out.println("Error: You have to choose a number from 1 to " + Bread.length);
            breadAndToast();
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input! Please Enter a Number.");
        breadAndToast();
    } finally {
        int fChoice = choice - 1;

        System.out.println("Your Choice is " + Bread[fChoice] + " and the Price is " + 
  breadPrice[fChoice]);
        System.out.print("How many do you want? ");
        int quantity = scanner.nextInt();

        subTotal = subTotal + (quantity * breadPrice[fChoice]);

        System.out.println("Total is: " + subTotal);

        orderAgain(1);
    }
}

private static void cakes() {
    System.out.println("You chose Cakes");
    System.out.print("What's Your Choice? ");

    int choice = 0;
    try {
        String choiceStr = scanner.next();
        choice = Integer.parseInt(choiceStr);
        
        if (choice < 1 || choice - 1 > Cake.length) {
            System.out.println("Error: You have to choose a number from 1 to " + Cake.length);
            cakes();
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input! Please Enter a Number.");
        cakes();
    } finally {
        int fChoice = choice - 1;

        System.out.println("Your Choice is " + Cake[fChoice] + " and the Price is " + 
  cakePrice[fChoice]);
        System.out.print("How many do you want? ");
        int quantity = scanner.nextInt();

        subTotal = subTotal + (quantity * cakePrice[fChoice]);

        System.out.println("Total is: " + subTotal);

        orderAgain(2);
    }
    
}

private static void donuts() {
    System.out.println("You chose Donuts");
    System.out.print("What's Your Choice? ");
    
    int choice = 0;
    try {
        String choiceStr = scanner.next();
        choice = Integer.parseInt(choiceStr);
        
        if (choice < 1 || choice - 1 > Donut.length) {
            System.out.println("Error: You have to choose a number from 1 to " + Donut.length);
            donuts();
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input! Please Enter a Number.");
        donuts();
    } finally {
        int fChoice = choice - 1;

        System.out.println("Your Choice is " + Donut[fChoice] + " and the Price is " + 
  donutPrice[fChoice]);
        System.out.print("How many do you want? ");
        int quantity = scanner.nextInt();

        subTotal = subTotal + (quantity * donutPrice[fChoice]);

        System.out.println("Total is: " + subTotal);

        orderAgain(3);
    }
    
}
private static void coffee() {
    System.out.println("You chose Coffee");
    System.out.print("What's Your Choice? ");
    
    int choice = 0;
    try {
        String choiceStr = scanner.next();
        choice = Integer.parseInt(choiceStr);
        
        if (choice < 1 || choice - 1 > Coffee.length) {
            System.out.println("Error: You have to choose a number from 1 to " + Coffee.length);
            coffee();
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input! Please Enter a Number.");
        coffee();
    } finally {
        int fChoice = choice - 1;

        System.out.println("Your Choice is " + Coffee[fChoice] + " and the Price is " + 
 coffeePrice[fChoice]);
        System.out.print("How many do you want? ");
        int quantity = scanner.nextInt();

        subTotal = subTotal + (quantity * coffeePrice[fChoice]);

        System.out.println("Total is: " + subTotal);

        orderAgain(4);
    }
    
}

private static void tea() {
    System.out.println("You chose Tea");
    System.out.print("What's Your Choice? ");
    
    int choice = 0;
    try {
        String choiceStr = scanner.next();
        choice = Integer.parseInt(choiceStr);
        
        if (choice < 1 || choice - 1 > Tea.length) {
            System.out.println("Error: You have to choose a number from 1 to " + Tea.length);
            tea();
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input! Please Enter a Number.");
        tea();
    } finally {
        int fChoice = choice - 1;

        System.out.println("Your Choice is " + Tea[fChoice] + " and the Price is " + 
 teaPrice[fChoice]);
        System.out.print("How many do you want? ");
        int quantity = scanner.nextInt();

        subTotal = subTotal + (quantity * teaPrice[fChoice]);

        System.out.println("Total is: " + subTotal);

        orderAgain(5);
    }
    
}

private static void orderAgain(int num) {
    System.out.println("Anything Else? ");
    System.out.print("Press Y for Yes, N for No and M for Menu: ");
    String again = scanner.next();
    
    switch (again.toLowerCase()) {
        case "y":
            if (num == 1) {
                breadAndToast();
            } else if (num == 2) {
                cakes();
            } else if (num == 3) {
                donuts();
            } else if (num == 4) {
                coffee();
            } else if (num == 5) {
                tea();
            }
            break; 
        case "n":
            System.out.print("Enter Payment: ");
            double pay = scanner.nextDouble();
            if (pay < subTotal) {
                System.out.println("Not Enough Payment");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Total price is " + subTotal);
                grandTotal = pay - subTotal;
                System.out.println("\n");                    
                System.out.println("The change is " + grandTotal);
```

This is the part where it gets confusing. I cannot determine how to solve for the breakdown of my change.

```
                int thousand = (int)grandTotal/1000;//This is where I get confused
                int remainderThou = thousand % 1000;
                int fiveHun = (int)grandTotal/500;
                int remainderFive = fiveHun % 500;
                int twoHun = (int)grandTotal/200;
                int remainderTwo = twoHun % 200;
                int oneHun = (int)grandTotal/100;
                int remainderOne = oneHun % 100;
                int fifty = (int)grandTotal/50;
                int remainderFif = fifty % 50;
                int twenty = (int)grandTotal/20;
                int remainderTwen = twenty % 20;
                int ten = (int)grandTotal/10;
                int remainderTen = ten % 10;
                int five = (int)grandTotal/5;
                int remainderFives = five % 5;
                int one = (int)grandTotal/1;
                int remainderOnes = one % 1;
               System.out.println("Number of Php 1000.00: "+remainderThou);//sorry for the messiness
               System.out.println("Number of Php 500.00: "+remainderFive);
               System.out.println("Number of Php 200.00: "+remainderTwo);
               System.out.println("Number of Php 100.00: "+remainderOne);
               System.out.println("Number of Php 50.00: "+remainderFif);
               System.out.println("Number of Php 20.00: "+remainderTwen);
               System.out.println("Number of Php 10.00: "+remainderTen);
               System.out.println("Number of Php 5.00: "+remainderFives);
               System.out.println("Number of Php 1.00: "+remainderOnes);
            }
            break;
        case "m":
            order();
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid Choose Again!");
            orderAgain(num);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and elaborate on your problem. I can only speak for myself but I have difficulties understanding what exactly you're struggling with and I won't dig through all that code and make guesses. - One additional advice: don't post _all_ your code but only the relevant parts you don't understand (and if possible a [mcve] with the emphasis on _minimal_).

Comment: I'll try one guess though: assume you have a `grandTotal` of 1500. Now `int thousand = (int)grandTotal/1000;` would result in `thousand = 1` because 1500/1000 = 1. `int fiveHun = (int)grandTotal/500;` is incorrect in that case. Why? Because it results in `fiveHun = 3` (1500/500). What you want instead is to divide the _remainder_ of the previous operation, so  `int fiveHun = (int)remainderThou/500;` in your case.

Comment: I get it now, thank you very much for the help. I've been stuck with this problem for 2 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate the amount of smaller bills/coins you need to take only the remainder of the previous operation:

```java
int thousand = (int)grandTotal/1000;
int remainderThou = grandTotal % 1000; // instead of thousand
int fiveHun = (int)remainderThou/500; // instead of grandTotal
int remainderFive = remainderThou % 500;  // instead of fiveHun
int twoHun = (int)remainderFive/200; // instead of grandTotal
int remainderTwo = remainderFive % 200; // instead of twoHun
......
```

And you should print the number of the bills/coins, not the remaining amount:

```java
System.out.println("Number of Php 1000.00: "+thousand);
System.out.println("Number of Php 500.00: "+fiveHun);
System.out.println("Number of Php 200.00: "+twoHun);
......
```

P.S. Right now you have an extreme case of code duplication. You should think of better methods to perform repeating/similar operations.

Comment: thank you for this brother. yeah I'll try to do better next time and its still new to me because I'm still a freshmen that is why my codes are pretty messy.